# Calcular sectores que contiene disco duro

Tags: python

**1​0. La mayoría de los discos duros se dividen en sectores de 512 bytes cada uno. Nuestro disco tiene un tamaño de 16 GB. Complete el espacio en blanco para calcular cuántos sectores tiene el disco**.

```
tamaño_disco = 16*1024*1024*1024
tamaño_sector = 512
cantidad_sector = tamaño_sector*tamaño_disco

print(cantidad_sector)
```

El resultado de sectores es: **8796093022208**
El examen me lo ha puesto como incorrecto, no se como operar la solución

Comment: ¿no tendria que ser `tamaño_disco/tamaño_sector`?

Answer (score 0):

La mayoría de los discos están divididos en sectores de 512 bytes cada uno.

```
tamaño_sector = 512
```

El disco duro tiene un tamaño de 16 GB.

```
tamaño_disco = 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
```

¿Cuántos sectores tiene el disco?

```
cantidad_sectores = tamaño_disco / tamaño_sector
```

Por lo tanto, este sería el cálculo:

```
tamaño_disco = 16*1024*1024*1024
tamaño_sector = 512
cantidad_sectores = tamaño_disco / tamaño_sector

print(cantidad_sectores)
```

Salida:

```
33554432.0
```